# Is there an Rust equivalent to the C preprocessor's __DATE__ and __TIME__ macros?

Tags: rust

I am looking for a way to embed the compile-time date and time into my program output for debugging purposes.

Comment: Seriously consider *not* doing this (or at least making it overridable at build time) because this completely precludes any ability to have a deterministic build.

Comment: https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/version-information/  and  https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/timestamps/

Comment: For anyone interested, I've made a self-contained tutorial with some snippets, about [generating version strings](https://vallentin.io/2019/06/06/versioning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. Use a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) instead.

See also:

- [Include git commit hash as string into Rust program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43753491/155423)